# How to get your text not to be parsed as a link?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

Is there some way to prevent my text to be automatically parsed as a link?

For example - this results in a broken link.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma^(-1)[1.32934039]

**I dont want it to be parsed as a link at all. Is there some way?**

Comment: Sadly, [Google Clickable Links](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mblbciejcodpealifnhfjbdlkedplodp) was the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surround it with [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) characters "`"

```
`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma^(-1)[1.32934039]`
```

`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma^(-1)[1.32934039]`

or wrap it in a **pre** tag

`<pre>http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma^(-1)[1.32934039]</pre>`

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma^(-1)[1.32934039]
```

Comment: Bravo for using each method to demonstrate the syntax of the other method.

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in a code block (highlight and click the binary icon):

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma^(-1)[1.32934039]
```

Or remove the *http*:

www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma^(-1)[1.32934039]